# Getting FB APP_ID from a FB Page

Tags: facebook

Hello I would like to know if it possible to get a FB APP_ID if I had created a Facebook page (no normal user) or this ID is just for applications? 
Thanks

Answer (score 9):

If you are facebook user login your id and go to "https://developers.facebook.com" link for registration as a facebook developer.

After confirm facebook developer Go to "APPS" tab create new Apps by enter your desire site **for example "http://chalachchabi.com/"**

Facebook will provide your FB APP_ID for further uses.

Answer (score 5):

If your question is whether you can use your FB Page ID as the `fb:app_id` meta tag, then no! Facebook's documentation is spare and contradictory on this.

Comment: Where did you get this information please ? (Which is maybe outdated after 4 years)

Comment: Sorry, I don't remember where I found this.. :(

Answer (score 4):

You do not have an app id but a page id.

i.e. http://graph.facebook.com/nike gives you:

```
 {
       "id": "15087023444",
       "name": "Nike",
       "picture": "http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/373573_15087023444_171119216_s.jpg",
       "link": "http://www.facebook.com/nike",
       "likes": 5645333,
       "category": "Product/service",
       "website": "http://www.facebook.com/nike",
       "username": "nike",
       "description": "Nike | Facebook",
       "talking_about_count": 44336
}
```

For more info, [Refer this link](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/)

[EDIT]: Facebook api has been updated: you need an access token to get data from this endpoint now.

Comment: Nope, it says: error "An access token is required to request this resource"

Comment: @CpILL Right: facebook api has changed since and you need an access token now as documented on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=<YOURS>&version=v2.8

Answer (score 4):

1. Login to the facebook developer console at:

   [developers.facebook.com](https://developers.facebook.com)
2. Here create a new facebook app for your website / page:

   `My Apps` > `Add a New App` > `Website`

Answer (score 0):

FB APP_ID is used only by applications, for e.g you have a website/application which does authentication using FB you will need to create a app at developers.facebook.com. Doing so would get you an APP ID and some more data used by other apps for social authentication. This APP ID can be used in HTML meta tag as follows:

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="your_app_id_goes_here">
```

Creating a FB page gets you a PAGE ID which can be used in HTML meta tag as follows:

```
<meta property="fb:pages" content="your_page_id_goes_here">
```