# Why is my open graph image meta tag isn't working on Facebook?

Tags: html, reactjs, meta-tags, share-open-graph

This is the very first time I try to deploy something. Though the webpage is for testing purposes and not finished yet but I want to share it for my friend to see.

When I share my web with some of my friends, I can't see the `open graph image`

It just displays like this

[image]

I'm just trying to implement a very simple static `open graph image`, not the dynamic one.

Here's how I set up my `head` in the `public/index.html` of my React-app

```
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
    <title>Mirai</title>
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Watch anime"
      />
    <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes"/>
    <meta name="application-name" content="Mirai"/>
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="Mirai"/>
    <meta property="og:title" content="Mirai"/>
    <meta property="og:description" content="Watch free anime"/>
    <meta property="og:type" content="website"/>
    <meta property="og:url" content="https://mirai-huy8856.vercel.app/">
    <meta property="og:image" content="https://s4.anilist.co/file/anilistcdn/media/anime/banner/101922-YfZhKBUDDS6L.jpg"/>
    
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
  </head>
```

Here's my [VERCEL App](https://mirai-huy8856.vercel.app/), I've `View Source` and saw that it has `og` meta tag in there, but Facebook refuses to read the image, what have I done wrong?

Here's the [Image](https://s4.anilist.co/file/anilistcdn/media/anime/banner/101922-YfZhKBUDDS6L.jpg) I tried to implement.

This is my folder structure in the ReactJS application.

[image: Folder Structure]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can test your OpenGraph settings on the Facebook Debugger here:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

It is worth noting with OpenGraph Image data you should supply additional data; namely:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="https://s4.anilist.co/file/anilistcdn/media/anime/banner/101922-YfZhKBUDDS6L.jpg"/>
    <meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpeg" >
<meta property="og:image:width" content="1800" >
<meta property="og:image:height" content="550" >
```

Further; looking at the page you give on your metadata OpenGraph URL tag
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fmirai-huy8856.vercel.app%2F

The de-bugger states:

> Missing Properties
> The following required properties are missing: fb:app_id

Comment: Thanks, but where can I look for app_id? I don't know anything about any of these, can you give me further instruction or some article? If can't I'll try to do more research, thanks for explaining what's wrong right now.

Comment: @Bunny you will get the app_id from Facebook itself. You need to make a Facebook page for your App ( I think) to get an App Id. Even if you don't use that facebook page.

Comment: @Bunny try here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8845082/getting-fb-app-id-from-a-fb-page